# JQuery gets loaded after script sometimes

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I implemented owlcarousel like this

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "Vendor_Module/js/owl.carousel.min"
    ],function($){
        $('#slider').ready(function() {

            var owl = $('#slider');

            owl.owlCarousel({
                dots: true,
                nav: true>,
                //further config ...
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

But half the time everything works properly and the other half it seem that my owlslider gets loaded after my jQuery and I get:

> TypeError: $ is undefined

How is that possible?

Comment: It's because the dependencies array is not guaranteed to load in order. Requirejs let's you define a `shim` config for non-AMD scripts (such as owl) where you can specify it's dependencies. http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: Thank you so much, that works! I'd accept you as the right answer, but can't since it's a comment.